# Why is .htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two rewrite rules, the first works, the second does not. Can someone please explain why?

I would like any url with the text "online-marketplace-development" to redirect to the URL http://jeyjoo.com/blog/online-marketplace-development-what-we-learnt

mod_rewrite is on, and all other rules work. My .htaccess is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
##following rule works
RewriteRule ^blog/blog(.*)$ http://jeyjoo.com/blog$1 [L,R=301]
##the following rule doesn't seem to do anything
RewriteRule ^online-marketplace-development(.*)$ http://jeyjoo.com/blog/online-marketplace-development-what-we-learnt
```

As requested, full .htaccess below:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

    #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type:s
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
    # 1 YEAR
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    # 1 WEEK is 604800
    <FilesMatch ".(xml|txt|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=904800, proxy-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    # 1 MIN
    #<FilesMatch ".(html|htm|php)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
    #</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects

RewriteRule ^blog/blog(.*)$ http://jeyjoo.com/blog$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^online-marketplace-development(.*)$ http://jeyjoo.com/blog/online-marketplace-development-what-we-learnt 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.jeyjoo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jeyjoo.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Thankyou

Comment: Why not: `RewriteRule ^blog/online-marketplace-development.*$ http://jeyjoo.com/blog/online-marketplace-development-what-we-learnt`

Comment: @anubhava I just tried this - but still no change.

Comment: no, there is just the top level file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104334/discussion-between-mike-fitzpatrick-and-anubhava).

Comment: Ji @anubhava , I moved as suggested to the start of RewriteEngine on - but still no luck
I also deleted caches and opened browser in Incognito to avoid page cache - still not redirecting

Comment: It might be still due to Joomla framework that is not hijacking this simple rule not work.

Answer (score 0):

The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. [see Apache docs on L flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Rule 1 is already applied for your second rule, so rethink your second rule from this perspective.

Comment: That is not how the [L] flag works. L will tell the rewrite engine to stop once the rule has been matched. In this case, the first rule has not been matched so the L flag does not get triggered. Also, once the url has been rewritten, the rewrite rules get rerun against the newly rewritten URL.

Comment: 1: The first line of my comment is an exact quote of Apache docs and

Comment: 2: the pattern in your problematic RewriteRule says: ^ (= if the following is at the beginning of the line)  and you probably want it say: just match every instance of the 'online-marketplace-development(etc)'. So i think online-marketplace-development(.*) (without the ^ and $) can work as you want.

Comment: that is not working either. Like I said, the rule directly above, of the same format (blog/blog) does work.

Comment: Again, I think that what you want to see has been handled already in the first  rule and with the L flag on that rule further handling is stopped.